# .NET Framework 4.8 is installed but not showing in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I am having issues while creating a project, it didn't show .Net framework 4.8. But I have already installed it. .Net SDK also installed.

When I check **Programs and features** in control panel, there is no source of Microsoft .Net framework 4.8. But it is showing .Net framework 7.0 and other versions.

After that I checked in Registry editor `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full` there it is showing 4.8 version. But its not showing in Visual studio 2022.

Tried with some solutions through google and youtube. There is no use

Comment: Maybe your project is a .NET Core one? .NET 7 is Core, not Framework. Try creating another Framework project instead.

Comment: Run the VS installer again, tick the .NET 4.8 *targeting pack*.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you had to go on the tool menu of visual studio then click on the manage preview feature then scroll down and check the checkbox "use previous of .NET SKD require a restart"

Screen shot of visual studio 2022: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BiiB.png)